# How to get rid of Firebase functions max timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I'm developing app with Firebase(Firestore, Firebase functions, Storage, etc)
I have one pubsub job which runs monthly(This job iterates over thousands of items and each item takes 1-3 seconds to run.)

Therefore, firebase functions timeout in 540 seconds(max limit for firebase functions).

As I researched, i need to move to Cloud App Engine(or something like that) or split into multiple jobs(But not sure how to split it).

Could you share how you achived this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout cannot be increased. You can switch to [Cloud Functions Gen 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-starting-cloudfunctions-v2) that has a 1 hour max timeout instead of 9 minutes. If that is insufficient then it would be best to use something like [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute).

Comment: 1 hour is not enough (it takes about 3-10 hours).Do you know other solution using Firebase?

Comment: @IoanMoldovan no, Cloud Functions is that only service where you can securely run your code. Where are those jobs coming from? You can maybe pick 1000 jobs per function that'll be roughly 50 minutes and Cloud Functions Gen 2 can handle those.

Comment: Firebase functions pubsub.

>Where are those jobs coming from

Comment: So a single function triggered by pubsub event takes that long? Then using Cloud Compute might be a better option. I don't have much details of what you are trying to do so I can't think of any alternatives.